# Python multiprocessing giving two different pid for same object

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

i'm using **Windows**

```
import multiprocessing
import os
class BaseModule(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Initialize time pid: ",os.getpid())
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()

    def get_pid(self):
        print("After new process pid: ",os.getpid())

    def run(self):
        self.get_pid()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = BaseModule()
    process.start()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Initialize time pid:  22148
After new process pid:  21244
```

In here same object get two different pid I need **full object create and run in new process using multiprocessing(same pid)?**

Comment: `multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)` and `super().__init__()` are redundant. Get rid of one of them. Beyond that, this is expected behavior: the process object is first created in the main process "initialize time", and then executed in a separate process "after new process". `__init__` does not get called when the object is copied to the new process. If you need a method that gets called when it's created on the other side, you need to override `__new__` or `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` (note this will only work when using the "spawn" context, and not with "fork")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a Way, in here I used a function for creating Object. Now I got same pid.

```
import multiprocessing
import os

class BaseModule:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Initialize time pid: ",os.getpid())

    def get_pid(self):
        print("After new process pid: ",os.getpid())

    def run(self):
        self.get_pid()

def use_multiprocessing():
    obj = BaseModule()
    obj.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=use_multiprocessing)
    process.start()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Initialize time pid:  18240
After new process pid:  18240
```

Comment: Yes, but do you understand why your initial code behaved the way it did, that is, printed two different process ids?

Comment: @Booboo According to my knowledge Object Initialize in Main Process And After The Initialize multiprocess start 'run' function as a new process. is it right?

Comment: Yes, the `run` method is executed in a new process.  There is an extra detail: You instantiated your `BaseModule` instance with `obj = BaseModule()` in the main process, so it was in the main process that `BaseModule.__init__` ran. But when the `run` method executes, it is done by the new process and so the `BaseModule` instance that was created in the main process has to first be transferred to the new process's address space by serializing and then deserializing the instance using module `pickle`. In effect, the `run` method is working with a *copy* of the original `BaseModule` instance.